# What is the relationship between the length of the circumradius and the inradius in $ \triangle ABC $?

Tags: plane-geometry

For reference: In a right angle triangle ABC, an interior bisector BD is traced, where I is or incenter, $\measuredangle B = 90 ^ o$ and $3BI = 4ID$. Find the relationship between the circumraio and inraio lenght of $\triangle ABC$. (Answer:3)

My progress:
I made the drawing
Inradius = r
Circumradius = R

$r=\frac{a+c-b}{2}=\frac{ab}{a+b+c}\\
R = \frac{b}{2}\\
\frac{R}{r} = \frac{b}{a+c-b}$

[image]

Comment: You are probably using $c$ instead of $b$. Typo?

Comment: @ACB..What would be the correct notation? I don't have information about this rule

Comment: Side opposite to $\angle B$ is $b$. And similar for other angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard notations for side lengths,

Please note that in $\triangle ADB$, as $AI$ is the angle bisector,

$AD:c = 3:4 \implies AD = \frac{3c}{4}$

Similarly in $\triangle CBD, CD = \frac{3a}{4}$

So, $b = 2R = AD + CD = \frac{3}{4} (a + c)$

$a + c = \frac{8R}{3} \tag1$

Now use the fact that $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle and hence,
$r = \frac{1}{2} (a + c - 2R)$

Answer (score 3):

Using the bisector’s property:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{AB}{BC}&=\frac{AD}{DC}\\
\\
\frac{BC}{DC}&=\frac{BI}{ID}
\end{align}
$$

And $AD+DC=AC$ & $\frac{BI}{ID}=\frac{3}{4}$ can you get $\frac{3}{4}\left(AB+BC\right)=AC$?

Comment: I would apply bisector theorem to $\triangle BAD$ and $\triangle BCD$. However, same result : )

Answer (score 1):

T.Poncelet:$BA+BC = AC+2r\\
R = \frac{AC}{2}\\
\frac{BA}{BI}=\frac{DA}{DI}\\
\frac{BC}{BI}=\frac{DC}{DI}\\
\therefore BA+BC = AC+2r\\
\frac{DA \cdot BI}{DI}+\frac{DC \cdot BI}{DI} = 2R+2r\\
\frac{4}{3}\cdot (DA+DC) = 2R+2r\\
\frac{4}{3}\cdot (AC) = 2R+2r\\
\frac{4}{3}\cdot (2R) = 2R+2r\\
\boxed{R =3r}$